# How to tell if JPA EntityManager.merge is doing an insert or an update

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

I am using JPA with EclipseLink and calling `EntityManager.merge()` to insert/update records in the database. The records come from an external system so I have no way of telling if they are new ones or updates on the existing ones.

Is there any way I can know what kind of operation (insert/update) is JPA performing when I call `merge()`?

Comment: To be sure what's going on under the hood, you could enable your jpa provider log to see the sql queries.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this behavior is transparent for you, so what merge does under the hood won't be directly told to you.

But since you didn't provide details on your merge operation, I have difficulties to imagine what use case you have, where you don't know if you update or insert. Questions in this regard would be

- are you using a generated or a manual id?
- are you using the version column?
- are you inserting/updating single entities or sub entities?

Comment: Manual Id, no version column, just single entities. The use case is that a 3rd party system sends a json containing updated and new records to my REST app, and I need to mark the new and updated records because this app needs to keep in sync with yet another server. I have a new, update, delete columns in every table, so I need to set new to true if the record was inserted or update to true if it was updated.

Comment: In that case I would think all you can do is select each record by its id and then set your flag columns accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like an answer to this question.

I can imagine numerous situations where I need to check if the object stores values ​​of a new record or an existing record.

To make history shorter, I get records from an external source (file, REST, whatever) and I need to know when to apply business validations to one form or another and also trigger the correct actions in each case.

The default solution found in several posts is with the use of an automatically generated id field.

When I have an automatically generated id I can check if its value is null (the id is automatically initialized in the registry's inclusion and returns filled when the data is fetched from the database). But when I do not have an automatically generated id, or, when it is a registry inclusion but its value has been improperly initialized by the application or external source, this logic does not apply (fails miserably).

I have done a query to the database for each record processed, but this makes an unnecessary excess of reads.

Another way (needs more testing) is to create a transient property in the entity called isNew. Initializing with true value in constructor and false in @PostLoad method. When the record is new, the constructor will mark the object as isNew = true; when it is read, the @PostLoad will mark isNew = false.

This may be the solution for you or maybe someone can tell us a better way to do this verification.

Comment: This sounds a clever idea. Did you end up using it?